# BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND no me funciona

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, bluetooth

Tengo un código de descubrimiento de dispositivos bluetooth.

Me llega a la opción `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` y `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` pero no descubre dispositivos teniendo el dispositivo de otro móvil y el del pc visibles.

Este es el código:

```
// Instanciamos un BroadcastReceiver que se encargara de detectar cuando
// un dispositivo es descubierto.
private final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Cada vez que se descubra un nuevo dispositivo por Bluetooth, se ejecutara
        // este fragmento de codigo
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Comienza la busqueda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
            // Acciones a realizar al descubrir un nuevo dispositivo
            // Si el array no ha sido aun inicializado, lo instanciamos
            if (arrayDevices == null)
                arrayDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

            // Extraemos el dispositivo del intent mediante la clave BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE
            BluetoothDevice dispositivo = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Añadimos el dispositivo al array
            arrayDevices.add(dispositivo);

            // Le asignamos un nombre del estilo NombreDispositivo [00:11:22:33:44]
            String descripcionDispositivo = dispositivo.getName() + " [" + dispositivo.getAddress() + "]";

            // Mostramos que hemos encontrado el dispositivo por el Toast
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Se ha detectado un nuevo dispositivo" + ": " + descripcionDispositivo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        // Codigo que se ejecutara cuando el Bluetooth finalice la busqueda de dispositivos.
        case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
            // Acciones a realizar al finalizar el proceso de descubrimiento
            // Instanciamos un nuevo adapter para el ListView mediante la clase que acabamos de crear
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new BluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, arrayDevices);

            lvDispositivos.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fin de la búsqueda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

    }

  /*  private void registrarEventosBluetooth() {
        // Registramos el BroadcastReceiver que instanciamos previamente para
        // detectar las distintos acciones que queremos recibir
        IntentFilter filtro = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        filtro.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

        //this.registerReceiver(bReceiver, filtro);
    }*/
};

private Button btnNewPairing;
private BluetoothAdapter bAdapter;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayDevices;
private ListView lvDispositivos;
private BluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter deviceArrayAdapter;
private boolean btn = true;
private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    this.bAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);

    if (!bAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // El Bluetooth está apagado, solicitamos permiso al usuario para iniciarlo
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        // REQUEST_ENABLE_BT es un valor entero que vale 1
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    btnNewPairing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNewPairing);
    btnNewPairing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                onStartButtonClick(btnNewPairing);

        }
    });





    lvDispositivos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDispositivos);
    // lvDispositivos.setAdapter(cadidateListAdapter);


    // ADAPTER
    //deviceArrayAdapter = new BluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter(this, BluetoothDevice);
    /*deviceCandidatesView.setAdapter(cadidateListAdapter);*/


    IntentFilter bluetoothIntents = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    bluetoothIntents.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
    bluetoothIntents.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    bluetoothIntents.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    bluetoothIntents.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    bluetoothIntents.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);


    registerReceiver(bReceiver, bluetoothIntents);

    //startDiscovery();
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        // Se ha encontrado el dispositivo. Podemos obtener la información
        String descripcionDispositivo = device.getName() + " [" + device.getAddress() + "]";
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Se ha detectado un nuevo dispositivo" + ": " + descripcionDispositivo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
};

public void onStartButtonClick(View button) {

    if (arrayDevices != null)
        arrayDevices.clear();

    if (isScanning()) {
        stopDiscovery();
        btnNewPairing.setText("START PAIRING");

    } else {
        btnNewPairing.setText("STOP PAIRING");
        startDiscovery();
    }
}

private void stopDiscovery() {
bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}

private boolean isScanning() {
    return bAdapter.isDiscovering();
}

public boolean startDiscovery() {
    bAdapter.startDiscovery();
    return true;
}

}
```

En el AndroidManifest tengo los siguientes permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Estoy usando la versión 6 de Android. 
¿Alguien ve algún error?

Comment: Ves algún error en el LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba definiendo cada `action` en un `intent` diferente de esta manera:

```
// Registrar el filtro de encontrar
IntentFilter filtroEncontrarDispositivo = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
_context.registerReceiver(_recibidor, filtroEncontrarDispositivo); // Hay que eliminarlo en el onDestroy!!

//Registrar el filtro de terminar la busqueda
filtroEncontrarDispositivo = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
_context.registerReceiver(_recibidor, filtroEncontrarDispositivo); // Hay que eliminarlo en el onDestroy!!

//Registrar el filtro de empezar la busqueda
filtroEncontrarDispositivo = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
_context.registerReceiver(_recibidor, filtroEncontrarDispositivo); // Hay que eliminarlo en el onDestroy!!
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Está bien intentar responder la inquietud, te recomiendo mejorar la calidad de tu respuesta para que ayudes a solucionar la inquietud del usuario que pregunta y de los que tendrán la misma inquietud y entrarán a esta publicación. La debes redactar mejor, con algún artículo o sitio de ejemplo que complemente tu respuesta. Te recomiendo leer este artículo: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).